# Increase the length of the Markdown sections in Careers

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-declined, jobs, character-limit

I've been trying to take [some advice that I received](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32135/feedback-requested-on-cv) earlier today to expand my "projects" section on my CV. Unfortunately, once I saved my CV, my additions were truncated at 4000 characters. The description does say to "briefly" describe the projects, so perhaps I'm being too long-winded, but I think that 4000 characters is a rather low ceiling, especially if you try to describe upwards of 4 separate personal projects as I was attempting to do.

I suggest the length of the Markdown sections on Careers be at least doubled, possibly more. I can't be the only one that ran into this limitation.

Comment: I'd say that truncating the text without warning should be classed as a bug. If there is a hard limit on the length, have the preview warn when it is reached.

Comment: @adrianbanks: Good point. Fortunately I didn't lose much as I constantly save and preview, but it definitely is a bug. Retagging as such.

Comment: I just got bitten by this, too. If the limit must be 4000--no problem--just give some feedback of that so I don't lose everything beyond it when I hit save...

Answer (score 2):

<sub>**This is based on my personal opinion and experiences**</sub>

I am not sure I agree. You should focus on highlights, and facts, with possibly links to a blog post going into more details. If you can't summarize a project in 4000 characters or less, there is something really wrong.

Although it is important, and in your case specifically warranted, to highlight projects and external involvement, I would only focus on the important details and highlights. At the end of the day very few companies are going to hire you only based on your CV, and your effectively trying to get an interview.

Therefore use the interview  for them to ask more about the particular project if they are interest, which gives you the chance to show competency.

**However** I do think the ability to add multiple different projects, each with a 4000 character limit might be a better approach.

Comment: +1 for suggestion of having multiple different projects